# how to make a unit test to assert if a property exist in a class or not using JUnit in java?

Tags: java, class, junit

I have a class A{ private a;} that contain one property 'a', I want to know how to write a unit test using JUnit to test if really Class A has a property 'a'.

thanks

Comment: This is not what unit tests are for.

Answer (score 0):

A unit test is designed to assert the behavior of a component/class in terms of API : the application public interface or simply said the methods/fields exported/accessible from a client of the class' point of view.
Asserting about the structure of a component/class is a completely different concern.
Generally you don't want to do such a thing as it validates nothing in terms of API and it is still more the case for private fields that the client of the class have not to be aware of.
In your case you should rather focus on  public/protected methods that use the `a` field.